# how can i dynamically pass value to db2 search clause 'like' while fetching result from other table

Tags: search, db2

Can someone help me how can i dynamically pass value to db2 search clause `like` while fetching result from other table.

I am trying this:

```
select * from table2 where file_name like '%(select file_name from table1)'
```

I've even tried CONTACT, using sysibm.sysdummy1 methods but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, this help;

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 
JOIN table1
ON table2.file_name LIKE CONCAT('%',table1.file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not having been shown the DDL for the files, nor any sample data and expected results from which a reader could determine if there might not be [other] considerations as implied obstacles, the following variation of the already-offered answer is more liberal in selecting what might be intended by the `select * from table2 where file_name like '%(select file_name from table1)'` from the OP; i.e. rather than effective predicates of `ends-with` [or a `starts-with`] the file-name value, the following achieves an effective predicate of `contains` the file-name value.

```
select /* t1.file_name, */ t2.*
from table2 as t2
inner join
     table1 as t1
  on  t2.file_name like '%' concat rtrim(t1.file_name) concat '%'
```